# How to wait 3 seconds after condition is true in an if statement

Tags: java, android

How can I make the if statement wait 3 seconds if it is true then check the other statement whether that is true?
I tried

```
if (value == 1) {
                red.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        red.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));                           
                        red.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            public void run(){
red.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF7D0000"));
                            }
                        }, 3000);
                    }
                },3000);
            }
```

but it didn't work for me and made the app really slow.

This is my original code that checks if the value exists in the array

```
if (value == 1) {

                        red.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));                           
                        red.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            public void run(){
red.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF7D0000"));
                            }
                        }, 3000);
            }
else if (value == 2) {
                yellow.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFF000"));
                yellow.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
yellow.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF7F7500"));
                    }
                }, 3 * 100);
            }
```

I have the color change for 3 seconds so that works, the thing I need to get to work is a delay of some sort that if the color changes it waits 3 seconds before changing color on another statement

The value comes from an int array with numbers from 1 to 4 in it in a random order. Should I use a switch instead of an if statement?

Comment: You are doing something else wrong, 2 Runnables won't slow down an app

Comment: The first code will wait for **6** seconds (nested Runnable)

Comment: You use the countdowntimer and set the backgroundcolor in onfinish function.

Comment: Have you tried `Thread.sleep(3000)` ?

Comment: yeah, I did, it makes the activity load very slow and when it does both colors change at the same time